# Python Matrix sorting via one column

Tags: python, sorting, matrix, numpy

I have a *n* x *2* matrix of integers. The first column is a series 0,1,-1,2,-2, however these are in the order that they were compiled in from their constituent matrices. The second column is a list of indices from another list.

I would like to sort the matrix via this second column. This would be equivalent to selecting two columns of data in Excel, and sorting via Column B (where the data is in columns A and B). Keep in mind, the adjacent data in the first column of each row should be kept with its respective second column counterpart. I have looked at solutions using the following:

```
data[np.argsort(data[:, 0])]
```

But this does not seem to work. The matrix in question looks like this:

```
matrix([[1, 1],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 7],
        ..., 
        [2, 1021],
        [2, 1040],
        [2, 1052]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [np.lexsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort):

> numpy.lexsort(keys, axis=-1)
>
> Perform an indirect sort using a sequence of keys.
>
> Given multiple sorting keys, which can be interpreted as columns in a
>   spreadsheet, lexsort returns an array of integer indices that
>   describes the sort order by multiple columns.

---

```
In [13]: data = np.matrix(np.arange(10)[::-1].reshape(-1,2))

In [14]: data
Out[14]: 
matrix([[9, 8],
        [7, 6],
        [5, 4],
        [3, 2],
        [1, 0]])

In [15]: temp = data.view(np.ndarray)

In [16]: np.lexsort((temp[:, 1], ))
Out[16]: array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])

In [17]: temp[np.lexsort((temp[:, 1], ))]
Out[17]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [3, 2],
       [5, 4],
       [7, 6],
       [9, 8]])
```

Note if you pass more than one key to `np.lexsort`, the *last* key is the primary key. The next to last key is the second key, and so on.

---

Using `np.lexsort` as I show above requires the use of a temporary array because `np.lexsort` does not work on numpy matrices. Since 
`temp = data.view(np.ndarray)` creates a view, rather than a copy of `data`, it does not require much extra memory. However,

```
temp[np.lexsort((temp[:, 1], ))]
```

is a new array, which does require more memory.

There is also a way to sort by columns *in-place*. The idea is to view the array as a structured array with two columns. Unlike plain ndarrays, structured arrays have a `sort` method which allows you to specify columns as keys:

```
In [65]: data.dtype
Out[65]: dtype('int32')

In [66]: temp2 = data.ravel().view('int32, int32')

In [67]: temp2.sort(order = ['f1', 'f0'])
```

Notice that since `temp2` is a *view* of `data`, it does not require allocating new memory and copying the array. Also, sorting `temp2` modifies `data` at the same time:

```
In [69]: data
Out[69]: 
matrix([[1, 0],
        [3, 2],
        [5, 4],
        [7, 6],
        [9, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks heaps @unutbu your a star! I look the second solution the best this one is exactly what I wanted :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea, just off by a few characters:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.matrix([[9, 8],
...                   [7, 6],
...                   [5, 4],
...                   [3, 2],
...                   [1, 0]])
>>> data[np.argsort(data.A[:, 1])]
matrix([[1, 0],
        [3, 2],
        [5, 4],
        [7, 6],
        [9, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification with this method @Bi Rico ;)