# Sorting all rows in numpy matrix by target-column

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

This seems been asked many times, however the answer I found not work now. Let's be simple, here I have a numpy matrix

```
data = np.matrix([[9, 8],
             [7, 6],
             [5, 7],
             [3, 2],
             [1, 0]])
```

Then sort by second column as below

```
[[1, 0],
[3, 2],
[7, 6],
[5, 7],
[9, 8]])
```

I tried a lot examples like [Python Matrix sorting via one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338110/python-matrix-sorting-via-one-column) but none of them worked.

I wondering maybe because the answers were posted years ago which do not work for newest Python? My Python is 3.5.1.

Example of my failed trial:

```
data = np.matrix([[9, 8],
             [7, 6],
             [5, 7],
             [3, 2],
             [1, 0]])
temp = data.view(np.ndarray)
np.lexsort((temp[:, 1], ))

print(temp)
print(data)
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean, which code exactly was tried and you know that np.matrix != np.array? (I really really really don't think, that these other answers are outdated if they are using basic numpy stuff; this would kill numpy for a lot of reasons!)

Comment: While taking another glance at your question: your title **Sorting numpy matrix by column** is misleading. The **working** example in your first link does that, but according to your example you only want to sort the column within the matrix (without rearranging the corresponding other columns too)!

Comment: @sascha You are right, so I have remove my second link. "Don't work " means the approved answer does not sort my matrix. i have put an example there.

Comment: Specify again what you really want: you want to sort all columns by one target-column (as the title says; permuting complete rows) or you want to sort only one column and don't touch the others ones, as your example shows. (the former has a working solution in your link)

Comment: @sascha Sorry for misleading, I mean sort all rows by one target-column. Which means, row with smallest number in target-column becomes first row, the row with second smallest number in target-column becomes second row, etc.

Comment: Then why is your example showing something else?

Comment: @sascha Modified. Apologized again for that, bad day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a moving target.

Sort each column independently:

```
In [151]: np.sort(data,axis=0)
Out[151]: 
matrix([[1, 0],
        [3, 2],
        [5, 6],
        [7, 7],
        [9, 8]])
```

Sort on the values of the second column

```
In [160]: ind=np.argsort(data[:,1],axis=0)

In [161]: ind
Out[161]: 
matrix([[4],
        [3],
        [1],
        [2],
        [0]], dtype=int32)

In [162]: data[ind.ravel(),:]  # ravel needed because of matrix
Out[162]: 
matrix([[[1, 0],
         [3, 2],
         [7, 6],
         [5, 7],
         [9, 8]]])
```

Another way to get a valid `ind` array:

```
In [163]: ind=np.argsort(data.A[:,1],axis=0)

In [164]: ind
Out[164]: array([4, 3, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32)

In [165]: data[ind,:]
```

To use `lexsort` you need something like

```
In [175]: np.lexsort([data.A[:,0],data.A[:,1]])
Out[175]: array([4, 3, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32)
```

or your 'failed' case - which isn't a fail

```
In [178]: np.lexsort((data.A[:,1],))
Out[178]: array([4, 3, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32)
```

here `data[:,1]` is the primary key.  `data[:,0]` is the tie breaker (not applicable in your example).  I'm just working from the docs.

Comment: Went through all your hints, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The approach in your link is working:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.matrix([[9, 8],
         [7, 6],
         [5, 7],
         [3, 2],
         [1, 0]])

print(data[np.argsort(data.A[:, 1])])

[[1 0]
 [3 2]
 [7 6]
 [5 7]
 [9 8]]
```

And now an example where it's better to see:

```
data = np.matrix([[1, 9],
         [2, 8],
         [3, 7],
         [4, 6],
         [0, 5]])
[[0 5]
 [4 6]
 [3 7]
 [2 8]
 [1 9]]
```

Comment: Sascha, I do appreciate your help and patience. I made a lot mistakes in my initial post. Biggest mistake was I confused by matrix and ndarray. Anyway, thanks again. Solved my problem

Comment: No worries. Have fun with python and numpy! You also should accept @hpaulj's answer because it is really detailed and solves your problem! Have a look at StackOverflows help to see why you won't need any "SOLVED" in title. You just mark one answer as **accepted**.

Comment: Just flagged. Well if possible I would like to flag you both